# change active state for jquery-ui button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui 1.11.  I have a button that I would like the active state to show that the button depresses when clicked.  Using the default functionality that I copied from the jquery-ui website, the text changes color from blue to coral.  I added a shadow to the button and I would like the active state to remove the box-shadow so that it looks like the button depresses when clicked.
This is my HTML:

```
<div id="rotation_btn_div">
<input id="rotation_schedule_btn" type="button" value="Create Schedule" />
</div>
```

This is my jquery function:

```
$(function () {
   $("#rotation_schedule_btn")
    .button()
    .click(function (event) {             
     event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Removing `.button()` removes the changes when the button is clicked (ie changes the text from  blue to coral). I would like to keep the text the same and just show the button as depressed when clicked.
This is my .css:

```
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for `:focus` .. But not too sure because `:active` should be working fine for this.. Are you looking for the CSS itself for a 'depressed' look ?

Comment: Yes.  I would just like the button to depress when clicked as oppose to the text changing color.  From what I have read, if you remove the box-shadow on the button it will look like it was depressed then pop back up.

Comment: I changed 'active' to 'focus'. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply CSS on input tag of type button so you can use CSS selector that way:

Use

```
input[type="button"]:active {
  box-shadow: none;        
}
```

instead of

```
button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

EDIT: You can add margins to button to make it more look like depressed button. You can adjust margin based on the box-shadow values to get your desired effect.

```
input[type="button"]:active {
  box-shadow: none;  
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left:3px;      
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That removed the box-shadow.  Did not give the affect that I thought though.  The button does not really look like it is depressed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @GloriaSantin, one of the way is that you can add some margins to make it look more like depressed button. See my edited answer

Comment: YES!  That is what I was after.  Thank you so very much!